# An unexpected error occurred: "EPERM: operation not permitted"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I have installed ReactJS to work on some project but this mistakes are making me sick.
First error appear when I tried to add package for my project.
So , I used :

```
yarn add @material-ui/icons
```

and after that It was fetching.
And I got this error message on the terminal line :

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\\React\\MyProject\\node_modules\\node-sass\\vendor\\win32-x64-93\\bindiinfo Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

I found some solutions and wanted to try. Whenever I try to use install command, it does not let me.
It gives this error

```
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-14T00_08_12_781Z-debug.log
enter code here
```

and whenever I click this error log, here is what I see.

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\XXXXXXXX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'yarn'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@5.3.0
3 info using node@v16.13.0
4 verbose npm-session 95556b4f7a104717
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yarn 188ms
8 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/yarn/-/yarn-1.22.17.tgz 120ms
9 silly pacote tag manifest for yarn@latest fetched in 352ms
10 verbose stack TypeError: cb.apply is not a function
10 verbose stack     at C:\Users\XXXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:287:18
10 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:199:5)
11 verbose cwd D:\React\projem
12 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
13 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\XXXXXXXX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yarn"
14 verbose node v16.13.0
15 verbose npm  v5.3.0
16 error cb.apply is not a function
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Please help me or I'll drive crazy so soon!
All the best everyone and THANK YOU! for your help.

Comment: Maybe you have your bundle running in watch mode in another terminal? If you can't find it, restart your computer and try again.

Answer (score 15):

Please stop the development server and install or add the packages.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue when I tried to install the blueprint package using yarn, I solved it by using npm package manager (npm install)

Answer (score 0):

Avast Antivirus was the culprit for me. Disable it.